# Replacement of new JacksonFactory to get google credential in Java

Tags: java, json, google-api, jackson

I'm trying to authenticate with google-api from a server with the following "old" code:

```
GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                        CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, code, "postmessage").execute();
        // Create a credential representation of the token data.
        GoogleCredential
                credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build()
                .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
```

From old releases of google-api for java, JSON_FACTORY was built doing something like this:

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
```

But since i've updated to version 1.15.0-rc, JacksonFactory is not found. Looks like it has been refactored or removed, but i can't find any example to replace this line of code.

What should i use? Implementation of JsonFactory for sure, but some standard implementation may already exist?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Finally found the JacksonFactory class. It has been separated and is available in the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

So the Java code doesn't change.

Comment: +1. Why does google make things so complicated? Docs aren't explained well

Comment: Yes, all these resources Google have and they can't find some developer to update there documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can too download the featured.zip version of the library:

http://dl.google.com/dl/googleapis/google-api-java-client-featured.zip