# Android "Could not find class JsonFactory" and "FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1" errors

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jackson, android-mapview, google-places-api

I am new to programming in Android and have been working through [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) tutorial for implementing Google Places in an app. When I try to use Google places to retrieve nearby places, my app crashes.

I believe the problem is here when I try to create a http request factory:

```
/**
 * Creating http request Factory
 * */
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setUserAgent("Searching Places..");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.setParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
```

Here are the resources from StackOverflow I used to create this method using google-api-java-client-1.15.0-rc:

[RequestFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147210/createrequestfactory-with-google-api-java-client-1-15-0-rc)
, [Jackson Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694955/replacement-of-new-jacksonfactory-to-get-google-credential-in-java)

Here is the class that the above method is contained in:

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;


public class GooglePlaces {
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

// Google API Key
private static final String API_KEY = "(HIDDEN ON PURPOSE)";

// Google Places search url's
private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

private double _latitude;
private double _longitude;
private double _radius;

/**
 * Searching places
 * 
 * @param latitude - latitude of place
 * @params longitude - longitude of place
 * @param radius - radius of searchable area
 * @param types - type of place to search
 * @return list of places
 * */
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius,
        String types) throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;

    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if (types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 * Searching single place full details
 * 
 * @param refrence
 *            - reference id of place - which you will get in search api
 *            request
 * */
public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

        PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

        return place;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}

/**
 * Creating http request Factory
 * */
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setUserAgent("Searching Places..");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.setParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the class where I am getting the "FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask#1" error:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheckAreaActivity extends Activity {

// flag for Internet connection status
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection detector class
ConnectionDetector connectionDetector;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Google Places
GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

// Places List
PlacesList nearPlaces;

// GPS Location
GPSTracker gps;

// Button
Button btnShowOnMap;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Places Listview
ListView placesListView;

// ListItems data
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// KEY Strings
public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; // Place area name

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.check_area_layout);
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.window_title);

    this.connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(
            this.getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet availability
    this.isInternetPresent = this.connectionDetector
            .isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!this.isInternetPresent) {
        // No Internet connection
        this.alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // Stop executing code
        return;
    }

    // Create GPS Class object
    this.gps = new GPSTracker(this);

    // Check if GPS location can get location
    if (this.gps.canGetLocation()) {
        Log.d("Your Location", "latitude: " + this.gps.getLatitude()
                + ", longitude: " + this.gps.getLongitude());
    } else {
        // Can not get user's current location
        this.alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this, "GPS Status",
                "Couldn't get location informaiton. Please enable GPS",
                false);
        // stop executing code
        return;
    }

    // Get listview
    this.placesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Button show on map
    this.btnShowOnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_map);

    // Call background Async task to load Google Places
    // After getting places from Google all the data is hown in listview
    new LoadPlaces().execute();

    /**
     * Button click event for show on map
     */
    this.btnShowOnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlacesMapActivity.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            intent.putExtra("user_latitude",
                    Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            intent.putExtra("user_longitude",
                    Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            intent.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // starting activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    /**
     * ListItem click event On selecting a list item SinglePlaceActivity is
     * launched
     */
    this.placesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int positon, long id) {
            // getting values from selected listItem
            String reference = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.reference)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SinglePlaceActivity.class);

            // Sending place reference id to single place activity
            // place reference id used to get "Place full details"
            intent.putExtra(KEY_REFERENCE, reference);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}



/**
 * Background Async Task to Load Google places
 */
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PlacesList> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(Html
                .fromHtml("<b>Search</b><br/>Loading Places..."));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected PlacesList doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
        try {
            // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
            // If you want all types places make it as null
            // Check list of types supported by google
            //
            String types = "cafe|restaurant";

            // Radius in meters
            double radius = 1609.34; // 1609.34 meters = 1 mile

            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                    gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nearPlaces;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise will get error
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList nearPlaces1) {
        super.onPostExecute(nearPlaces1);

        nearPlaces = nearPlaces1;

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        // updating UI from Background Thread

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                // Get json response status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if (status.equals("OK")) {

                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {

                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // Place reference won't display in listview
                            // - it
                            // will be hidden
                            // Place reference is used to get
                            // "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, place.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, place.name);

                            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                        }

                        // list adapter
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                CheckAreaActivity.this, placesListItems,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                        KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME },
                                new int[] { R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                        // Adding data into listview
                        placesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                } else if (status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")) {
                    // Zero results found
                    alert.showAlertDialog(
                            CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Near Places",
                            "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                            false);
                } else if (status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Places Error", "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                            false);
                } else if (status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(
                            CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Places Error",
                            "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                            false);
                } else if (status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Request is denied", false);
                } else if (status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request", false);
                } else {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(CheckAreaActivity.this,
                            "Places Error", "Sorry error occured.", false);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.check_area_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204581/asynctask-error-after-the-new-android-sdk-updates) resource from StackOverflow in writing the AsyncTask.

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.renterview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- GPS access Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >

    <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <!-- Splash Screen Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.renterview.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.renterview.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Check Area Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity" />

    <!-- Single Places Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.example.renterview.SinglePlaceActivity" />

    <!-- PlacesMapActivty -->
    <activity android:name="com.example.renterview.PlacesMapActivity" />

</application>
```

Here is what LogCat is showing me:

```
08-03 17:06:12.490: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 7% free 2421K/2596K, paused 36ms, total 48ms
08-03 17:06:12.529: I/dalvikvm-heap(895): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.901MB for 4633616-byte allocation
08-03 17:06:12.590: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6945K/7124K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
08-03 17:06:12.659: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 6945K/7124K, paused 9ms+5ms, total 70ms
08-03 17:06:13.611: D/libEGL(895): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
08-03 17:06:13.629: D/(895): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a157c58, tid 895
08-03 17:06:13.650: D/libEGL(895): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
08-03 17:06:13.660: D/libEGL(895): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
08-03 17:06:13.740: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 17:06:13.760: D/OpenGLRenderer(895): Enabling debug mode 0
08-03 17:06:17.260: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 17:09:05.439: D/GPS(895): GPS Enabled
08-03 17:09:05.439: D/Your Location(895): latitude: -85.07573166666667, longitude: 33.580275
08-03 17:09:05.519: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_CONCURRENT freed 33K, 2% free 8343K/8488K, paused 70ms+49ms, total 217ms
08-03 17:09:06.152: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 17:09:06.282: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 17:09:07.229: E/dalvikvm(895): Could not find class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory', referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>
08-03 17:09:07.229: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 523 (Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;) in Lcom/google/api/client/json/jackson2/JacksonFactory;
08-03 17:09:07.239: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
08-03 17:09:07.249: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken;)
08-03 17:09:07.249: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken.ordinal, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.convert
08-03 17:09:07.249: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3644: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken;.ordinal ()I
08-03 17:09:07.249: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
08-03 17:09:07.259: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve static field 998 (UTF8) in Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonEncoding;
08-03 17:09:07.259: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
08-03 17:09:07.259: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonGenerator
08-03 17:09:07.259: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3608: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;.createJsonGenerator (Ljava/io/Writer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;
08-03 17:09:07.259: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
08-03 17:09:07.269: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser
08-03 17:09:07.269: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3609: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
08-03 17:09:07.269: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
08-03 17:09:07.269: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser
08-03 17:09:07.269: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3609: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
08-03 17:09:07.269: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
08-03 17:09:07.281: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser
08-03 17:09:07.281: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3610: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
08-03 17:09:07.281: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
08-03 17:09:07.281: I/dalvikvm(895): Could not find method com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createJsonParser, referenced from method com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser
08-03 17:09:07.281: W/dalvikvm(895): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3611: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;.createJsonParser (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
08-03 17:09:07.289: D/dalvikvm(895): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
08-03 17:09:07.299: D/dalvikvm(895): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0e15 at 0x05 in Lcom/google/api/client/json/jackson2/JacksonFactory;.<init>
08-03 17:09:07.299: W/dalvikvm(895): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:44)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.renterview.GooglePlaces$1.initialize(GooglePlaces.java:109)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:122)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.renterview.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:53)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(CheckAreaActivity.java:195)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(CheckAreaActivity.java:1)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-03 17:09:07.349: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  ... 4 more
08-03 17:09:08.159: W/EGL_emulation(895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895): Activity com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412a33c0 V.E..... R....... 0,0-322,175} that was originally added here
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412a33c0 V.E..... R....... 0,0-322,175} that was originally added here
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity$LoadPlaces.onPreExecute(CheckAreaActivity.java:175)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.example.renterview.CheckAreaActivity.onCreate(CheckAreaActivity.java:109)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-03 17:09:08.929: E/WindowManager(895):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I believe that the JsonFactory error might be the cause of all the other erros that are popping up on LogCat?

Here are the .jar files I have in my libs folder:

```
android-support-v4.jar
google-api-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
gson-2.1.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
```

Project Build Target I have (API Level 17)(Google APIs is checkmarked):

```
Google APIs[Android 4.2.2]
Android Dependencies
```

My inexperience in android development has left me stuck for the moment. Any and all help would be greatly appreaciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .jar is for jackson-core version 1.9 but the Google API you're using depends on Jackson 2.  The package structure com.fasterxml.* doesn't exist in the 1.9 .jar, it's all .org.codehaus.*

You can get the 2.x .jar at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload if you look under "Downloads, 2.x".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Downloading and using jackson-core-2.1.3.jar and removing jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar solved this issue. However, now I have realized that this code is outdated due to GoogleMaps Android APIV2..